# How to support multilingual for angular Website

Tags: internationalization, angular11

I am beginner to Angular. i do not know how do support a website for multilingual using angular 11.And i have some dynamic contents in the website .I want this to include the multilingual support. can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions. You can use angular built in i18n (https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview). But it requires handling bundles with server because angular i18n creates separate bundle for each language you want in your application. For example, if user switches to english you should load bundle for english language and reload the page and same for other languages.

Another one is Transloco (https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/) which is popular. It will allow you change i18n in runtime without creating multiple bundles. You need to configure app to work with this package and create `json` files with keys and translated values for each language. Transloco has good documentation and examples.

Another popular is ngx-translate (https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) which works similar to Transloco.

Also if your project is small you can handle translations manually (update/add new ones) but in case of large project better way is to upload i18n resource files to 3rd party services where translator will translate everything and you can then import translated files to your project.

So it depends of your project which one to select but you can compare advantages and disadvantages and choose necessary.

Comment: i am trying ngx-translate using translate pipe. It working fine in html . but it does not work  in ts file. i need some examples related to my issue.can anyone share this

Comment: Since you are using @ngx-translate, in your ts component files you can import TranslateService which is exported from @ngx-translate/core. Then declare it in the constructor and use it in the component's logic. For example: this.translateService.instant('[your key from the json file]')